# How to correct a typo/misspelling in a question title?

Tags: support

Is there a way of correcting spelling mistakes in questions? i.e. in the title. This obviously becomes the page title and gets embedded in the URL so it has an impact on searchability (and hence onward usability).

I stupidly misspelled Ubuntu as "Ububtu" and would like to be able to correct it (or ask someone with sufficient privileges to do so). The post in question is [Ubuntu Server 12.04 can access LAN but not internet](https://serverfault.com/questions/390986/ububtu-server-12-04-can-access-lan-but-not-internet)

D'oh!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should have an edit link under your question, with which you can make any necessary corrections.

The impact on searchability is probably not as great as you think -- Google is pretty smart.  A search for `Ubuntu can access LAN but not internet` returns your question as the top result - typo and all :)

Comment: You star! I didn't realise that the 'edit' on the question as a whole would let me edit the title too. I would +1 if I could! (Shame I can't port my StackOverflow rep here.)

Comment: @PaulMasri, as soon as you get 200rep on any site, you will an account association bonus on all other sites, that will give you the basic privileges everywhere in the stackexchange network.